# Vb.net regex escaping optional backslash optional in the end of a string

Tags: regex

I have a string and i want to know if it includes some pattern in the end of it.
I want to know if it has "jobs" or "jobs/" the "/" is optional
for example:

www.example.jobs/
www.example.jobs

So far i have this:

```
 \.(com|org|edu|net|jobs?/|gov)$
```

The problem is that if i have a string that ends with "jobs" it doesn't catch it.

Comment: Do you want to also match `job/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `?` optional quantifier to `/`

```
\.(com|org|edu|net|jobs?/?|gov)$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bI9qJ6/1)

- `/?` ensures that the `/` is matched zero or one time, making it optional

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `/` so the pattern becomes

```
.+\.(?:com|org|edu|net|jobs|gov)\/?$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR6tE0/1)